# Why does this program use return with various different exit codes?

Tags: perl, shell, return, return-value

What is the meaning of return with different values in exit_Code below:

```
sub exit_Code {
    my $testResult = shift;
    if ( $testResult eq "PASS" ) {
        return 0;
    } elsif ( $testResult eq "FAIL" ) {
        return 1; }
    elsif ( $testResult eq "ABORT" ) {
        return 40;
    } else {
        print "Invalid testResult argument passed..\n";
        print "Valid testResults are: PASS, FAIL or ABORT\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Vague question is vague.
This is just a function that returns some numbers when it's invoked. Without seeing more of the program we can't comment on what those numbers might mean.

Comment: @KevinPaton: That is a horrible edit. First, the argument to `return` is not a suffix. Second, you didn't even preserve the case and formatting of `exit_Code`. Third, gratuitous use of bold. The question was bad to begin with, and this just makes it that epsilon worse.

Comment: Can you roll back the edit or re-edit then?

Comment: after finding the answer i really find the question stupid. But believe me, I did not know that before. Thanks all.

Comment: @KevinPaton: I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *nix, programs have return values, which can be evaluated (e.g., by using the `$?` environment variable). `0` means the program completed without an error. Values larger than `0` mean some error occurred, and the documentation should state what each unique value means. While Perl functions do not share the semantics of returning `0` upon successful execution, this function is presumably used to return the exit code **for the program**.

Comment: The question was about a Perl subroutine, not about a excutable.

Comment: @shashidtj: You may have gotten the answer, but not from this. Unix programs follow a convention for their return status values: zero for success, non-zero for error. Perl subroutines have no such convention; a Perl subroutine returning `0` does *not* necessarily mean that it succeeded. I suggest *not* accepting this answer (you can re-click the check mark to unaccept it).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes It;s true that the above answer is not completely right but it gave me a approach by which i was able to find the answer. And yeah thanks for your suggestions. I'm really new here and glad that people are so helpful.

Comment: @shashidtj: Now that I've taken a closer look at the code in your question and at this answer, I need to back off from at least part of what I wrote above. The function is named `exit_Code`, which strongly implies that its result is going to be used as an argument to `exit()`. Given that, the answer makes sense (though I would have made the connection between the function's result and it use as the program's exit code more explicit). Incidentally, the final `else` clause just prints an error message (to stdout; it should be to stderr) and fails to return a value; that's very poor practice.

Comment: I just tried to withdraw my downvote (see my previous comment), but the system won't let me do so until the question is edited. I suggest you add something to make it clear that the value returned by the function will (presumably) be used as the program's exit status.

Comment: @KeithThompson Added a sentence at the end to clarify my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably add the word "presumably". The name `exit_Code` is certainly suggestive, but we are making a presumption here.

Comment: @shashidtj: I suggest you accept this answer again (and I apologize for my previous poorly thought out advice).

Comment: @KeithThompson that's what i've mentioned in my previuos comment. Thanks anyway.